# Database corruption after trying to reinstall Rules Module

Tags: rules, database

I was getting a database error when trying to op the Rules UI so I tried to reinstall the module. I uninstalled the Rules Modules and Rules UI module then tried to install the Rules module and now every page of the sites gives this error:

```
Additional uncaught exception thrown while handling exception.

Original

PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table &#039;sgda_arcade.rules_config&#039; doesn&#039;t exist: SELECT base.id AS id, base.name AS name, base.label AS label, base.plugin AS plugin, base.active AS active, base.weight AS weight, base.status AS status, base.dirty AS dirty, base.module AS module, base.access_exposed AS access_exposed, base.data AS data FROM {rules_config} base WHERE (base.plugin = :db_condition_placeholder_0) AND (base.active = :db_condition_placeholder_1) ; Array ( [:db_condition_placeholder_0] =&gt; reaction rule [:db_condition_placeholder_1] =&gt; 1 ) in EntityAPIController->query() (line 152 of /srv/arcade/sites/all/modules/custom/entity/includes/entity.controller.inc).

Additional

PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table &#039;sgda_arcade.rules_config&#039; doesn&#039;t exist: SELECT base.id AS id, base.name AS name, base.label AS label, base.plugin AS plugin, base.active AS active, base.weight AS weight, base.status AS status, base.dirty AS dirty, base.module AS module, base.access_exposed AS access_exposed, base.data AS data FROM {rules_config} base WHERE (base.plugin = :db_condition_placeholder_0) AND (base.active = :db_condition_placeholder_1) ; Array ( [:db_condition_placeholder_0] =&gt; reaction rule [:db_condition_placeholder_1] =&gt; 1 ) in EntityAPIController->query() (line 152 of /srv/arcade/sites/all/modules/custom/entity/includes/entity.controller.inc).
```

Is there anything I can do to fix this?

Comment: did you actually uninstall the modules after disabling them or just disable and re-enable them?

Comment: I actually uninstalled them. Disable then uninstall.

Comment: well the uninstall in drupal should go in and actually drop all the database tables as part of its processing, so, something else must be going on to not allow them to be recreated upon re-enabling so I guess you are now in mysql dba mode :(

Comment: Hmm, any clue could cause that?

Comment: no clues without being there, sorry ;(  I would go through your logs and look for clues there;  could be permissions, eg, your database user isn't allowed to create tables but can read them?  odd of course but odder things have happened.

Comment: that's very strange there are not error in the log and when I execute a: show grants for 'root'@'localhost'; It says: GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED

Comment: well then somehow the tables aren't being dropped when you run the module uninstall routine and or they aren't being created (because they are already there or drupal thinks they are because the uninstall failed or something) so the best thing I can suggest is disable the module, run the uninstall routine, look at the database and then re-enable it and check the database to see if the tables are back.

Comment: I don't think I can do that. I get this error on every page of the site and I also get it when I try and run and drush commands. Is my only option try to restoring from a backup?

Comment: you could go into the module install file and look what these tables are supposed to look like and re-create them manually; but, I think a restore from backup might be the eventual end result

Comment: (you could also go into the system table and manually disable the module but now we are getting surgical and not something I can talk you through right now)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out the drive on which my database was installed had run out of disk space, so as JimaJamma suggested, the table could not be created by the rules module.